# C++ Class Pointers and ownership

Tags: c++, pointers, lifetime

So im recreating Pong in C++ (Using ncurses for terminal hijinks since trying to do it JUST with console proved to be much harder than I thought). This is sorta meant to "Refresh on C++" as it's been awhile, and I want to do some Hobby game development using Unity.

I figured "Well I should at LEAST make a simple game first in C++ to prove I can even start on Unity). Pong is an obvious choice as you need to handle: Objects, Game State, Collision, Movement Vectors-ish.

In refreshing on C++ I had to look up a lot of newer stuff, and remind myself of things forgotten (It's been 10 years since i've touched C++). One thing I can't quite remember super well is the intimate details of pointers with regards to classes. (BTW a very basic version with the ball and paddles/collision is here: https://pastebin.com/5NHjEjxX I've only spent a couple of hours on it so far).

Specifically one thing I couldn't quite remember is shown here:

```
const int boardWidth = 60;
const int boardHeight = 12;
Ball ball = Ball(-1,1,(boardWidth/2),(boardHeight/2));
Ball *p_ball = &ball;
Paddle paddle1 = {4,(boardHeight/2),3};
Paddle *p_paddle1 = &paddle1;
Paddle paddle2 = {(boardWidth-4), (boardHeight/2),3};
Paddle *p_paddle2 = &paddle2;
Board board;
```

(This is in the Game class initialization. Although I sort of wondered if I should be putting this in the constructor). nevertheless....specifically when I declare `Ball ball = Ball(-1,1,(boardWidth/2),(boardHeight/2));` or `Paddle paddle1 = {4,(boardHeight/2),3};` where are these items "Sitting" in memory? Im assuming the heap? Also how would I go about deleting these the proper way (for instance the ball goes out of bounds and I need to create a new ball?)

I know there are some things about ownership...and I feel like this is the wrong way using & since p_ball for instance won't actually "Own" that class but simply just be able to reference it right? (I think there is a term "smart pointers" but that hadn't really been out yet last time I touched C++). If there is a more proper way i'd love to know!.

I've also been told that it's probably better to pass by reference in these functions anyways to avoid using pointers and avoid creating a pointer all together.

Comment: `Ball ball = Ball(…)` ball is on the stack but components of it may, or may not, be on the heap. Use a debugger along with the source for `Ball` to examine it and understaqnd what's going on. `p_ball` is just a pointer to ball so is also on the stack.

Comment: What you've been told is good advice. Don't mess with pointers until you encounter some problem that doesn't have an easier solution. And perhaps if you do think you've encountered such a situation, ask about the best way to handle it. (Likely by passing references, but maybe something else.)

Comment: Also, you probably don't need to delete the ball when it goes out of bounds. You can simply create a new temporary ball that is in bounds and set the old ball equal to the new ball and then let the new ball go out of scope. If you were tracking rounds in a game and you went from round 4 to round 5, you wouldn't delete the old round counter and create a new one set to 5 -- you'd just set the existing round object to 5. Same thing with the ball. Try to deal with values whenever possible.

Comment: Please start from here: https://www.amazon.com/dp/0134997832/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_ep_dp_sibqBbB8M0P13 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of those are automatic variables.  Their lifetime will end when you reach the end of the current scope.  There's no need to delete them; that will happen automatically as soon as you reach the end of the current scope.

---

If you want your `Game` class object to own the ball, paddles, and board it would make sense for them to have member scope.  i.e.

```
class Game {
public:
    static const int BOARD_WIDTH = 60;
    static const int BOARD_HEIGHT = 12;

    Game()
        : ball{-1, 1, BOARD_WIDTH / 2, BOARD_HEIGHT / 2},
          paddle1{4, BOARD_HEIGHT / 2, 3},
          paddle2{BOARD_WIDTH - 4, BOARD_HEIGHT / 2, 3}
    {}

private:
    Ball ball;
    Paddle paddle1;
    Paddle paddle2;
    Board board;
};
```

These member objects will share the lifetime of the `Game` object.

---

Pointers are just objects that point to other objects.  They don't affect the lifetime of the object they point to.  You can, for example, return pointers to an object's members from a method.  Just take care that your pointers don't outlive the objects they point to.

If you want to make your `Game` class contain pointers to the other objects then you would need to manage the lifetime of those other objects yourself.  For example, you could dynamically allocate them.  This has very few advantages over having the objects contained directly in the `Game` object though, and adds a considerable amount of complexity and overhead.

Here I'm using `std::unique_ptr` to do the memory management:

```
class Game {
public:
    static const int BOARD_WIDTH = 60;
    static const int BOARD_HEIGHT = 12;

    Game()
        : ball{std::make_unique<Ball>(-1, 1, BOARD_WIDTH / 2, BOARD_HEIGHT / 2)},
          paddle1{std::make_unique<Paddle>(4, BOARD_HEIGHT / 2, 3)},
          paddle2{std::make_unique<Paddle>(BOARD_WIDTH - 4, BOARD_HEIGHT / 2, 3)},
          board{std::make_unique<Board>()}
    {}

    // Copying is implicitly disallowed since std::unique_ptr is non-copyable.
    // You could implement a copy constructor and copy assignment operator to
    // do a deep copy

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Ball> ball;
    std::unique_ptr<Paddle> paddle1;
    std::unique_ptr<Paddle> paddle2;
    std::unique_ptr<Board> board;
};
```

Or you could do the memory management manually if you really want to, but there's little-to-no benefit to doing so:

```
class Game {
public:
    static const int BOARD_WIDTH = 60;
    static const int BOARD_HEIGHT = 12;

    Game()
        : ball{new Ball(-1, 1, BOARD_WIDTH / 2, BOARD_HEIGHT / 2)},
          paddle1{new Paddle(4, BOARD_HEIGHT / 2, 3)},
          paddle2{new Paddle(BOARD_WIDTH - 4, BOARD_HEIGHT / 2, 3)},
          board{new Board()}
    {}

    // You must implement these yourself to do a deep copy when doing manual
    // memory management.  I've opted to delete them to disallow copying a Game object
    Game(const Game&) = delete;
    Game& operator=(const Game&) = delete;

    ~Game() {
        // every instance of 'new' must have exactly one matching 'delete'
        delete board;
        delete paddle2;
        delete paddle1;
        delete ball;
    }

private:
    Ball* ball;
    Paddle* paddle1;
    Paddle* paddle2;
    Board* board;
};
```

Comment: If I was making them as pointers would it be done the same way? (or is it better to just use references for the methods in this case)

Comment: Thanks this helps a ton! the C++ info out there is so scattered and the examples can be very different from each other.

Answer (score -1):

All variables in your example are located on the stack. They only live as long as the [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) they are located in. The heap only gets used when you use new or a smart pointer equivalent.